# wxOwnerDrawnComboBox on OSX has an extra row at the bottom of the scroll

Tags: c++, macos, user-interface, combobox, wxwidgets

I've implemented a custom [wxOwnerDrawnComboBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_owner_drawn_combo_box.html) based on the API docs. I then placed it on a `wxPanel` then used [SetPopupMaxHeight](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_combo_ctrl.html#a24f043ce5c1287904a899c22f2dc7ce9) to limit the combo popup to show only 3 items at a time. But the popup **shows an extra white row at the bottom of the popup window**.

Here are screenshots (I implemented it on the **minimal_cocoa** sample project):
[image: pic1] [image: pic2]

As shown, there are only 6 items but at the end of "item 5", there's an extra row.

Some notes on the issue:

- It is always the default white (checked by customizing the bg of the
  other rows to black)
- It only happens when using `SetPopupMaxHeight`
- It only happens on Mac (i.e. no issue on Windows)
- Clicking on that extra row will close the popup (so I guess it's drawn part of the popup window)

Here is the code (simplified for the **minimal_cocoa** project):

---

```
// CUSTOM CLASS DECLARATION

class MyOwnerDrawnComboBox : public wxOwnerDrawnComboBox
{
public:
    static int getItemHeight()
    {
        return 25;
    }

public:
    // ctor

    MyOwnerDrawnComboBox(wxWindow* parent,
                         const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
                         const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
                         int n = 0,
                         const wxString choices[] = NULL,
                         long style = wxODCB_STD_CONTROL_PAINT)
    : wxOwnerDrawnComboBox(parent,
                           wxID_ANY,
                           wxEmptyString,
                           pos,
                           size,
                           n,
                           choices,
                           style,
                           wxDefaultValidator,
                           "MyOwnerDrawnComboBox")
    {
    }

    // overrides

    virtual void OnDrawItem (wxDC& dc, const wxRect& rect, int item, int flags) const
    {
        dc.SetTextForeground(*wxRED);

        // for debugging purposes, display the item index instead
        wxString label = wxString::Format("item %d", item);
        dc.DrawLabel(label, rect, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }

    virtual wxCoord OnMeasureItem (size_t item) const
    {
        return 25;
    }

    virtual wxCoord OnMeasureItemWidth (size_t item) const
    {
        return -1; // use default
    }
};

// CUSTOM CLASS USAGE

wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
wxString items[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}; // unused
MyOwnerDrawnComboBox* odcb = new MyOwnerDrawnComboBox(panel,
                                                      wxDefaultPosition,
                                                      wxSize(150, 30),
                                                      6,
                                                      items);
odcb->SetPopupMaxHeight(3 * MyOwnerDrawnComboBox::getItemHeight());
sizer->Add(odcb, 0, wxALL, 10);
sizer->Layout();
panel->SetSizer(sizer);
```

---

I've tried a few things:

1. Used the default `OnDrawItem` method (same issue)
2. Checked for extra calls to `OnDrawItem` (no extra calls)
3. Adjusted the returned item height in `OnMeasureHeight` (same issue)
4. Checked the behavior on the **samples/combo/combo.cpp** sample (same issue)

   [image: combo-cocoa-1]  [image: combo-cocoa-2]

---

Some info on my wxWidgets build:

- Cloned it directly from their [github](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git) repo
- Made no changes to the wxWidgets source aside from defining `wxUSE_XTEST 1` in **setup.h**

  - I checked and `wxUSE_ODCOMBOBOX` and `wxUSE_COMBOCTRL` are `#define`'d
- Used the following options for **../configure**

  - `--with-osx_cocoa`
  - `--with-macosx-version-min=10.7`
  - `--with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk`
  - `--enable-debug`
  - `--disable-shared`
  - `--enable-unicode`
  - `--prefix="$(pwd)"`

Some info on my env:

- macOS 10.12.5 (Sierra)
- Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
- **minimal_cocoa** displays **wxWidgets 3.1.1**

---

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
I'm working around it for now by not using `SetPopupMaxHeight` anymore.

If someone has a solution though, do share.

Comment: did you try the combo sample? Does it behave the same?

Comment: @Igor Yes, I tried it. All the combo implementations have the same issue, whether it's the odcb or a ComboCtrl with a custom ComboPopup (I edited the post to add screenshots).

Comment: how did you configure the library? When you tried the sample - did you change it in any way? Did you receive any warnings during the build?

Comment: @Igor I made no changes to the sample code, aside from adding `SetPopupMaxHeight` calls. I made some changes to the Xcode project Build Settings though, which I've edited into the post (please see my updates at the bottom), along with what I used to configure the library.

Comment: @Igor There are a LOT of warnings (250+) when building the sample, most being _Deprecations_ on 10.12, with some _Preproc_ issues (ex. _`wxUSE_CRASHREPORT` is not defined, evaluates to 0_) and some _Semantic Issues_ (ex. _implicit declaration in C99_). There was also a warning before that `wxUSE_OWNER_DRAWN` is not defined, but defining it did not fix the issue (and I think it's not really used? Because there's already a `wxUSE_ODCOMBOBOX` defined in setup.h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing some changes to the wx source.

**src/generic/vscroll.cpp**

`wxVarScrollHelperBase::DoScrollToUnit`:

```
// determine the real first unit to scroll to: we shouldn't scroll beyond
// the end
size_t unitFirstLast = FindFirstVisibleFromLast(m_unitMax - 1, true);
if ( unit > unitFirstLast )
    unit = unitFirstLast;
```

Pass `false` instead to `FindFirstVisibleFromLast`.

This will allow the method to consider an item as the first item even though the last item is only partially visible ("partially" here, based on my testing, is really like "almost fully visible", with only about ~2pts that are hidden). With `true`, the scroll moves down to the next item, thereby adding the extra row.

**src/generic/odcombo.cpp**

`wxVListBoxComboPopup::OnMouseMove`:

```
        // Only change selection if item is fully visible
        if ( (y + fromBottom) >= 0 )
        {
            wxVListBox::SetSelection((int)line);
            return;
        }
```

To match the 2pt borders being considered in `wxVListBoxComboPopup::GetAdjustedSize`, I changed the IF condition to `(y + fromBottom + 2)` to allow moving the mouse over the last item in the scrolled window, even though it isn't fully visible.

**src/generic/vlbox.cpp**

```
    else // line is at least partly visible
    {
        // it is, indeed, only partly visible, so scroll it into view to
        // make it entirely visible
        // BUT scrolling down when m_current is first visible makes it
        // completely hidden, so that is even worse
        while ( (size_t)m_current + 1 == GetVisibleRowsEnd() &&
                (size_t)m_current != GetVisibleRowsBegin() &&
                ScrollToRow(GetVisibleBegin() + 1) ) ;
```

Comment-out that while-loop to disable auto-scrolling when the mouse pointer is over the partially visible item.